# Cancellation in ASP.NET Core UserManager

Tags: asp.net-core, cancellation, asp.net-core-3.0, cancellation-token

I am currently implementing some services based on the design of the UserManger of Asp.Net Core Identity. 
In the Implementation i wondered how the usermanager is possible to support cancellation if there is no possibility to pass a Cancellation Token into the methods of the UserManager.

I also saw that there is an Cancellation Token Property inside the usermanager (With default value) that is used internally by it and will passed to the used async methods. But this property is not accessable due to its protection level

```
protected virtual CancellationToken CancellationToken => CancellationToken.None;
```

How can i pass my Cancellation token that i am using in my controller for example into the user manager ? Do i have to overload it and pass it via a new method into it ?

```
public class MyUserManager : UserManager<MyUser>
{
    /* ... Other stuff... */

    protected override CancellationToken CancellationToken  {get;set;}

    public void SetCancellationToken(CancellationToken cancellationToken)
    {
         this.CancellationToken = cancellationToken;
    }

}
```

Is that the correct way to accomplish Cancellation with the userManager ? In case of yes: Why is this different to other components where cancellationTokens are used like EF Core where you have to pass the CancellationToken via method parameter ?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

`UserManager` handles cancellation internally, and gets the cancellation token from `HttpContext.RequestAborted`. As such, you don't need to pass in a cancellation token, and that's why the methods don't accept one.

Comment: But where does he get access to the HttpContext ? The only way he would able to do that is the injected ISericeProvider but he just uses this for the purpose to get the ILookupProtectorKeyRing / ILookupProtector or the TokenProviders. I Can't see the line where he does anything with the HttpContext or even set the cancellationToken anywhere ?

Comment: DbContext has an internal service provider. The point is that you don't need to worry about this at all. UserManager takes care of handling cancellation out of the box. You don't do anything.

Comment: Any hints how to use the `UserManager` in a `BackgroundService`? From time to time the cancellation-token seems to be triggered which has nothing to do with the background service.

In my service I have a loop which ckecks some condition and if they pass a new `IServiceScope` is created from which I retrieve the `UserManager`. If it's always bound to some (unrelated) `HttpContext` that's a real mess. How should I use it independent of any `HttpContext`?

Comment: It only uses HttpContext if it exists (web request). It doesn't create one. As far as cancellation goes, that's a function of some external process, anyways. Like the user closing the connection on the other end. There's no point to supporting cancellation in something unattended like a background service, since nothing would ever act to cancel.

Comment: I guess I have to investigate, what is triggering the cancellation. I have here an Asp.Net Core app with a hosted service, so more or less both worlds. The only cancellation in a background service which can occur is the stopping of the service. Thank you!

Comment: That's what I was trying to say, buy perhaps wasn't clear. The actual service stopping is not a cancellation, that will abruptly close the SQL connection and the DB will handle that naturally. Cancellation is for times.when everything is good, everything is working in proper order, but for some reason (usually user-initiated) the op is no longer necessary. That's simply not something that will occur on a background service.

Answer (score 0):

In the `UserManager`, set `CancellationToken = CancellationToken.None`, and use it for all tasks.

https://github.com/dotnet/aspnetcore/blob/b9efadc59ddbf6743775244622fb95301dd1846c/src/Identity/Extensions.Core/src/UserManager.cs#L53

As noted in [the Microsoft docs](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.threading.cancellationtoken.none?view=net-5.0):

> The cancellation token returned by this property cannot be canceled

So all the tasks of `UserManager` will except after calling the `Dispose()` method, because `ThrowIfDisposed` is called for all tasks.